# Use custom fonts in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, fonts, embedded-resource

I am trying to make a GUI like a iPad/iPhone, so to be able to make it look good, of course you need to use a font like Apple. I have downloaded it - MyriadPro-Semibold and put it in the control panel font's folder, but when selecting a font, it is not there. I found this online:

> Label1.Font = Resources.GetFont(Resources.FontResources.MyriadPro-Semibold)

I suspect it is C (minus the ";" at the end of the line), but I don't know. Should I have to put the font in the resources or what?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Myriad Pro is an OpenType font.  Only WPF supports such fonts, Winforms requires a TrueType font.

Just one hint, when you copy Apple fonts then be sure to not be successful.  Apple has a lot of lawyers and isn't afraid to use them.  Especially when the font is used for their corporate logo.

Comment: Thanks- can I convert it? P.S. I don't have a Mac so I downloaded it from here: [FontZone](http://fontzone.net/font-details/MyriadPro-Semibold/). I think this is legal!?!?!?